# Image does not appear when using "figure" but works otherwise

Tags: graphics, floats

I am new to Latex. This is my first paper and I am trying to insert images with captions. I have looked up other similar questions/answers but to no avail. Here is my code that does not display images:

```
% This stuff is up top
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

...

\begin{figure}
\caption{Histogram of errors of $k_{cvx}$ and $k_{ccv}$ - mean errors 3.8cm and 3.88cm respectively, $\phi = 0.05$ rad (2.9 degrees) with a max error of 11cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{errors_kcvx_005rad_038cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{errors_kccv_005rad_0388cm}
\label{fig:plot1}
\end{figure}
```

Nothing shows up. However, if I comment out all the figure stuff, I see the two images that I want to make up my figure:

```
%\begin{figure}
%   \caption{Histogram of errors of $k_{cvx}$ and $k_{ccv}$ - mean errors 3.8cm and 3.88cm respectively, $\phi = 0.05$ rad (2.9 degrees) with a max error of 11cm}
%   \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{errors_kcvx_005rad_038cm}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{errors_kccv_005rad_0388cm}
%   \label{fig:plot1}
%\end{figure}
```

How can I use the figure functionality and add captions? Thank you.

Comment: Did you check on the next pages if the float moved there?

Comment: Yep, no images appear anywhere in the document.

Comment: We need a complete code MWE.

Comment: I am not sure what that is, is it a log file of some sort?

Comment: A Minimal Working Example, preferably using example images from the MWE package.  It should include everything from \documentclass to \end{document}. but only what is needed to show the problem.

Comment: How to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).